# How to show a command only in explorer context menu in vscode extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to provide a command, where the user select some files and directories in explorer panel, call out the context menu and select the command.

This command must operate on a set of files, so I don't expect the user to directly execute it from command palette, because the `registerCommand` callback will not receive selected files as arguments.

I can't just remove it from `contributes.commands` in `package.json`, because `contributes.menus["explorer/context"].command` requires it to exist in `contributes.commands`.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using the `commandPalette` menu item.
By default, any command that is being registered will be visible in commandPalette, we can disable it from showing it in the commandPalette with a simple `when` clause.

Example:

```json
"commands":[
    {
        "command":"extension.sayHello",
        "title":"Hello World"
    }
],
"menus":{
    "commandPalette":[
        {
            "command":"extension.sayHello",
            "when":"false"
        }
    ],
    "explorer/context":[
        {
            "command":"extension.sayHello",
            "when":"true"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will show the command only in the explorer and not in the commandPalette.